# In BizTalk how can I assign dynamic Send port to Party and Party Agreement?

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2013r2

How can I assign dynamic port to Party and Party Agreement?

In BizTalk 2013 R2 how can I assign dynamic port to Party and Party Agreement?

I have created a dynamic Send Port and wants to assign this to Party Agreement Setup but this is not showing here, although I can see other Static Ports over here.

Comment: How can this be used in Orchestration? I am trying to use this but not showing the Context

Comment: You should use the edit link below the question to add more details to a question rather than in comments

Comment: See  Configuring a Dynamic Send Port for Messages over AS2  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb246003.aspx